# How to save an image from an URL which does not contain any image file extensions (e.g. png) in Python?

Tags: python, rest

I have read a similar question's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url), but it only says about an URL that contains an image file extension (e.g. *https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuyvH.png*) and this method does not work for an URL without any image file extension (e.g. *https://picsum.photos/id/128/100/100*).

I used the code below to save and show an image when the URL does not contain an extension. But it did not work.

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

response = requests.get("https://picsum.photos/id/128/100/100")

file = open("sample_image.png", "wb")
file.write(response.content)

file.close()

img = mpimg.imread('sample_image.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Now, how can I load and save this image in Python?

Comment: all of those links contain the file extension (or at least I get redirected to a link that contains the extension and the `requests` should too)

Comment: you don't necessarily need to know the exact extension to save the image, just use `png` or `jpg` and you should be fine

Comment: I have updated my description, but yes you are right. The links which are redirected contain extensions. But, is there a way in Python which simulates this behavior (links do not contain extensions, but redirected links are)? Because this is how pics from lorem picsum are required to be used.

Comment: "and it does not work for an URL without any image file extension (e.g. https://picsum.photos/id/128/100/100)." What do you mean by "does not work"? What happened when you tried using that code? How is the result different from what you expect? Also: are you actually using the `requests` third-party library for this? If not, the `[python-requests]` tag is inappropriate. Either way, you should show at least some code. As a refresher, please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get do the following, after getting the response:

```
_, extension = response.headers["content-type"].split("/")
fname = f"sample_image.{extension}"
file = open(fname, "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

Comment: idk the technical name, but they are called f-strings, just fancy way of editing strings. that whole line is equivalent to: `fname = "sample_image."+extension`